# BCP import only half of csv file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

I have a problem with BCP. I try to import CSV file to table through view as below:

```
bcp vImport in "CSV\data.csv" -U[user] -P[password] -S[server] -ddb -c -t; -F2 -e"CSV\error.err"
```

The file contains about 900 rows, but BCP has loaded only 400 rows. I was looking for parameter or Db setting, but without success.

I cut the file to 400 rows than BCP loaded 200 rows.

Comment: There have to be some error in your input file, bcp handles 900 rows without any special configuration.

Comment: @Oscar I cut the file to 400 rows than BCP loaded 200 rows

Comment: What's in the error.err file?

Comment: @Brian It's epty

Comment: It appears that something is wrong with your file or with your choice of terminators. I suggest you get a file viewer that shows you the hex values in your file so you can investigate your choices against what is actually present in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was that source table has got one more column than csv file so last column of table was filled with next row from csv file.